# Is $\text{span}_{L^0} (\mathcal S)$ sequentially closed under convergence in probability?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Fix a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ and $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal A$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$. Let $L^0(\mathcal F)$ denote the set of equivalence classes of $\mathcal F$-measurable real random variables $X$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal A,P)$. For $\mathcal S \subset L^0(\mathcal A)$ define

$$\text{span}_{L^0(\mathcal F)} (\mathcal S):=\bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_iX_i: X_i\in \mathcal S, Y_i\in L^0(\mathcal F), n\in\mathbb N\bigg\}$$

Am asking whether $\text{span}_{L^0(\mathcal F)} (\mathcal S)$ is sequentially closed under convergence in probability.

Consider the following example: $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P):=([0,1],\mathcal B[0,1],\lambda)$ with $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and $\mathcal F$ the trivial $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$. Define

$$\text{span}_{L^0(\mathcal F)} (\mathcal S):=\text{span}_{L^0(\mathcal F)} \big\{1_{[0,1-2^{-n}]}: n\in\mathbb N\big\}$$

Then $1_{[0,1-2^{-n}]}$ converges in probability to $1_{[0,1]}$, but $1_{[0,1]}\notin \text{span}_{L^0(\mathcal F)} (\mathcal S)$.

**Question:** Can this happen if $\mathcal S$ is finite?

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT: An attempt for the case $\mathcal F=\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal S=\{X_1,X_2\}$.

Let $(Y_n):=(W^1_nX_1+W^2_nX_2)$ be a sequence in $\text{span}_{L^0(\mathcal F)} (\mathcal S)$, and suppose that $(Y_n)$ converges in probability to $Y\in L^0(\mathcal A)$. There is a subsequence $(Y_{n_k})$ of $(Y_n)$ such that $Y_{n_k}\to Y$ as $k\to\infty$, $P$-almost surely. Let $N\in \mathcal A$ be a null set outside of which $Y_{n_k}\to Y$ pointwise. Define

$$W_1(\omega):=\begin{cases} 
 \frac{Y(\omega)}{2X_1(\omega)}& \text{if } \omega\in \{X_1\neq 0\}\cap\{X_2\neq 0\}  \\
      \frac{Y(\omega)}{X_1(\omega)}& \text{if } \omega\in \{X_1\neq 0\}\cap\{X_2=0\}  \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}$$

$$W_2(\omega):=\begin{cases} 
 \frac{Y(\omega)}{2X_2(\omega)}& \text{if } \omega\in \{X_1\neq 0\}\cap\{X_2\neq 0\}  \\
      \frac{Y(\omega)}{X_2(\omega)}& \text{if } \omega\in \{X_2\neq 0\}\cap\{X_1=0\}  \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}$$

Then $W_1,W_2 \in L^0(\mathcal A)$ and $Y_{n_k}\to Y=W_1 X_1 +W_2 X_2 \in \text{span}_{L^0(\mathcal F)} (\mathcal S) $ outside of $N$, i.e.  $Y=W_1 X_1 +W_2 X_2$ $P$-almost surely.  So $\text{span}_{L^0(\mathcal F)} (\mathcal S)$ is sequentially closed.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think your example is badly written, $1_{[0,1/2^n]}$ goes pointwise so in probability to $1_{\{0\}}$ and $1_{[0,1]}$ is in $span_{L^0}(\mathcal S)$ for $n=0$.

Comment: @blamethelag You are right I corrected now. Thanks.

Comment: If $X$ is almost surely not null then its span is $L^0$ which is closed. I suspect something similar in the case of arbitrary random variables but we might have to play with their support. Also notice that the “convergence in probability” topology is metrizable so closed is equivalent to sequentially closed.

Comment: @blamethelag Do you see an example where $\text{span}_{L^0} (X)$ is not closed if $X$ is not almost surely not null?

Comment: What have you tried for the finite case?

Comment: @supinf I made an edit with an attempt for the case $\mathcal A=\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal S$ with two elements.